# get Header GET programmably in c#

Tags: c#, header, cgi

I want to get GET Header from http://pabetting.howden.press.net/. It uses CGI. I found that i can navigate through site using referrer URL sent by GET header. I tried to use WebRequest, WebBrowser but it didn't help. I only managed to get a Header that didn't contains referrer. How I can get a Get Header which contains referrer URL? I need also to get that URL which is in referer

Here is the picture: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/72/trolok.jpg/

Comment: The *client* puts the referrer header on. It's not really clear what you're trying to do here. (And CGI is hardly "some weird scripts".)

Comment: Your picture is from a request header, not a response header.

Answer (score 0):

In an HttpWebRequest, you can set the referrer property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.referer.aspx